# Comandos de repetição para restringir um valor válido

Tags: c, c++

Preciso de um código que leia um número maior que 1, e caso seja digitado um número menor ou igual a zero, seja pedido outro número, e conseguinte possa ser testado se verdadeiro.

Queria um auxílio para concluir meu código.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()


{
int num,primo;
num=1;
do
{
    printf("Informe um numero primo maior que 1:");
    scanf("%d",&primo);

    if((primo%num)==0)
    printf("Numero primo",primo);

    else
    printf("Numero não primo");
}
while(primo>1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi outros problemas, formatei melhor para facilitar a leitura. Veja que mesmo parecendo bobagem, os espaços, a pontuação, tudo ajuda.

Se o problema é ficar repetindo o pedido até que ser digitado um valor inválido então você deve só colocar dentro da repetição o que precisa ser feito de novo e a única coisa que deve ser feita de novo é o pedido de digitação. O resto ficar fora do laço.

E se você deve ficar dentro do laço enquanto a condição for inválida, você deve inverter o operador do que é válido. Ou seja, se você precisa que o valor seja `> 1`, ele deve ficar preso como inválido se o valor for `<= 1`.

E este é outro aprendizado importante. O oposto de `>` é `<=` e não `<` como muitos podem pensar. Obviamente o oposto de `<` é `>=`. Se o oposto de `>` fosse `<`, então o valor igual seria o que? Ficaria perdido no espaço? O igual tem que entrar em um dos lados.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num = 1, primo;
    do {
        printf("Informe um numero primo maior que 1:");
        scanf("%d", &primo);
    } while (primo <= 1);
    if (primo % num == 0) {
        printf("Numero primo %d", primo);
    } else {
        printf("Numero não primo");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/MmxOuE). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ryksducz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ValidationRange.c).

Não é assim que se acha o primo, mas vou deixar você arrumar porque não é o foco da pergunta.

Comment: Muito obrigado!